# Can't get Token based authentication working with NancyFX

Tags: authentication, nancy, http-token-authentication

I am trying Token based authentication with NancyFX. Token is getting generated perfectly but when I am passing header in Get Request, I can't get pass this.RequiresAuthentication() and getting unauthorized error.

Here is my token format

```
Token:{ token: "ZGVtb1VzZXINCmFkbWlufG5vbmFkbWluDQo2MzU1MDU5NjU4NzExNTE5MzkNCk1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMzsgV09XNjQpIEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0LzUzNy4zNiAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIENocm9tZS8zOC4wLjIxMjUuMTExIFNhZmFyaS81MzcuMzY=:QerS8B701zoC1xqlvSxuz0EbrBDtfgEzkDWzlEj9ChA=" }
```

Am I passing wrong way?

I have also tried

```
Token:{ ZGVtb1VzZXINCmFkbWlufG5vbmFkbWluDQo2MzU1MDU5NjU4NzExNTE5MzkNCk1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMzsgV09XNjQpIEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0LzUzNy4zNiAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIENocm9tZS8zOC4wLjIxMjUuMTExIFNhZmFyaS81MzcuMzY=:QerS8B701zoC1xqlvSxuz0EbrBDtfgEzkDWzlEj9ChA=}
```

and also

```
"Token:{ ZGVtb1VzZXINCmFkbWlufG5vbmFkbWluDQo2MzU1MDU5NjU4NzExNTE5MzkNCk1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMzsgV09XNjQpIEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0LzUzNy4zNiAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIENocm9tZS8zOC4wLjIxMjUuMTExIFNhZmFyaS81MzcuMzY=:QerS8B701zoC1xqlvSxuz0EbrBDtfgEzkDWzlEj9ChA=}"
```

But nothing work.

Please let me know if any more details are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the authorization header must simply read "Token ZGVtb1VzZXINCmFkbWlufG5vbmFkbWluDQo2MzU1MDU5NjU4NzExNTE5MzkNCk1vemlsbGEvNS4wIChXaW5kb3dzIE5UIDYuMzsgV09XNjQpIEFwcGxlV2ViS2l0LzUzNy4zNiAoS0hUTUwsIGxpa2UgR2Vja28pIENocm9tZS8zOC4wLjIxMjUuMTExIFNhZmFyaS81MzcuMzY" (no quotes).

The brackets in the documentation threw me off as well.

Comment: You saved me. Else I need to right custom function to detokenize and validate token. Thank...